# Trying to read a file into a struct array, but for loop only displays the first index and the rest as zero?

Tags: c++

My assignment is to read a file into a dynamic struct array and manipulate the data.  I need it to display all of the team names along with their win=loss score, but it only seems to display the first row. Is there something wrong with how I'm reading in my file?

The test input file looks like this:

```
New England Patriots,3,13,0

Buffalo Bills,15,1,1

Carolina Panthers,9,7,1

Jacksonville Jaguars,10,6,1

Miami Dolphins,7,9,0

Green Bay Packers,11,5,1

San Francisco 49ers,4,12,0
```

But my code results as this:

```
Team W-L

New England Patriots 3-0

 0-0

 0-0

 0-0

 0-0

 0-0

 0-0
```

Included: iostream, fstream, string

My code:

```
struct teamInfo
 {
     string teamName;
     int win;
     int loss;
     int playoffs;
     int winlossdiff;
 };

void winloss( struct teamInfo *arr, int index)

int main()
{

        teamInfo *arr;
        char fileName[100];
        int choice,size;

        ifstream file;

        file.clear();
        cout<<"Please enter file name:";
        cin>>fileName;

        while(!fileName)
        {
                cout<<"Error. Enter valid file name:\n";
                cin>>fileName;

        }

        file.open(fileName);
        file>>size;
        arr = new teamInfo[size];

        for (int i =0; i<size; i++)
        {
                getline(file,arr[i].teamName,',');
                file>>arr[i].win;
                file>>arr[i].loss;
                cout<<arr[i].loss;
                file>>arr[i].playoffs;
        {

        file.close();

        winloss(arr,size);  
        delete[] arr;            

        return 0;                  
}        

void winloss( struct teamInfo *arr, int index)
{
        cout<<"Team W-L\n";                   

        for(int i=0; i <index; i++)      
        {
           cout<< arr[i].teamName<<" "<<arr[i].win<<"-"<<arr[i].loss<<"\n"<<endl;
        }            

}
```

Apologies if the formatting it odd, I'm new.

Answer (score 1):

After `file>>arr[i].win`, the next character in the stream is a comma `,`. The next operation, `file>>arr[i].loss`, then fails because a comma cannot be parsed as part of an integer.

Comment: I see, that make sense thank you! If you don't mind me asking, what do you think I should do? I tried getline to parse through it but it seemed to just skip over some of the teams